# How to restore selection?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to copy some text from a `<textarea>` to your clipboard:

```
function copy() {
    var txtInput = document.getElementById('txtInput');
    txtInput.select();
    var success;
    try {
        success = document.execCommand('copy');
    } catch(err) {
        success = false;
    }
    if(!success) {
        alert('Copy failed');
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to mess with the user's selection. How can I restore it to whatever it was before?

I only need to support the latest version of Safari.

**Clarification:** I want to copy *all* the text (as this function does) but without changing their existing selection.

Comment: why not grab the text, storing in a variable, then reseting it to that variable afterwards?

Comment: restore the whole text area, or the selected portion of the text area?

Comment: also, I don't think its supported in safari 9.1

Comment: @JordanHendrix What do you mean? I'm not changing the text. I'm overwriting the user's existing selection via `txtInput.select()` which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get it now.  This should work in Chrome 50+ at least. It will allow you to highlight the text, copy it, maintain the highlight and ensure its on the clip board.

```
function getSelectionText() {
  var txtInput = document.getElementById('txtInput');

  if (txtInput.selectionStart != txtInput.selectionEnd) { // check the user has selected some text inside field
    //get actual text
    var selectedtext = txtInput.value.substring(txtInput.selectionStart, txtInput.selectionEnd);
    //set original highlight
    txtInput.setSelectionRange(txtInput.selectionStart, txtInput.selectionEnd)
    return selectedtext;
  }
}

function copy() {
  //check our log to be sure
  console.log(getSelectionText());
  try {
    window.document.execCommand('copy');
  } catch (err) {
    alert('Copy failed');
  }
}
```

Try it out:

https://jsfiddle.net/kwscmech/4/

And here's a reference:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/copytoclipboard.shtml

UPDATE: as per comment

```
function getSelectionText(cb) {
  var txtInput = document.getElementById('txtInput');

  if (txtInput.selectionStart != txtInput.selectionEnd) { // check the user has selected some text inside field
    //get selected text
    var selectedtext = txtInput.value.substring(txtInput.selectionStart, txtInput.selectionEnd);
    var partial = {
      start: txtInput.selectionStart,
      end: txtInput.selectionEnd
    };

    //get all text
    var allText = txtInput.select();

    cb();

    //set original highlight
    txtInput.setSelectionRange(partial.start, partial.end);
  }
}

function copy() {

    console.log('copying')
  getSelectionText(function() {
    //check our log to be sure
    console.log('callback');
    try {
      window.document.execCommand('copy');
    } catch (err) {
      alert('Copy failed');
    }
  })
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kwscmech/5/

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was asking. I want to copy *all* the text but without changing their selection if they have one. As far as I know, you can't copy text without first selecting it, so I have to select all the text, copy it, then reset their selection.

Comment: That looks like what I wanted. Thank you !!